# How do i calculate a projection sum using sql?

Tags: sql, database, sum, projection

I have the following Lease table

```
Lease_id Apt_id Resident_id Start_Date End_Date   Upfront_Amt Monthly_Fee
101      110    1001        02/01/2015 07/31/2015 250          500
102      111    1002        03/01/2015 02/29/2016 1000         2000
103      112    1003        04/01/2015 03/31/2016 750          1500
```

What I wanted to calculate was a projection of earnings from the Monthly fee.
For example:

```
01/2015 0 (No lease active)
02/2015 500 (From Lease 101)
03/2015 500 + 2000 (From Lease 101 and 102)
04/2015 500 + 2000 + 1500 (From Lease 101, 102 and 103)
:
:
08/2015 2000 + 1500 (From lease 102 and 103)
etc..
```

Is there a way to do this efficiently with a single query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select
    format(m.Lease_Month, 'MMM yyyy') as Lease_Month,
    sum(sum(Monthly_Fee)) over (partition by m.Lease_Month) as Projection
from
    <list of months> m left outer join
    Lease l
        on m.Lease_Month between l.Start_Date and l.End_Date
group by
    m.Lease_Month
order by
    m.Lease_Month;
```

There are lots of ways to generate a list of months. Here's one:

```
declare @num_Months int = 16;
declare @start_Date date = '20150101';

with months as (
    select @start_Date as Lease_Month, 1 as Month_Num
    union all
    select dateadd(month, Month_Num, @start_Date), Month_Num + 1
    from months
    where Month_Num < @num_Months
) ...
```

Put it all together and see it run here: http://rextester.com/YUAF69376

Comment: Thank you that works perfectly well and I can use one of the calendar tables in the database and it's quick and efficient. Thanks again. Any suggestions on where I can learn advanced sql (advanced for me) like this?

Comment: @MadhuraKshirsagar I wish I could point you to a single tutorial/reference but I just don't know of a good one to recommend. How much of it do you understand?

Answer (score 1):

something like this could work:

```
SELECT l1.[Start_Date], SUM(l2.SumFee)
FROM Lease as l1, (SELECT [Start_Date],SUM(Monthly_Fee) As SumFee
FROM Lease
GROUP BY [Start_Date]) as l2
WHERE l1.[Start_date]>=l2.[Start_Date]
GROUP BY l1.[Start_Date]
```

another way to do that would be:

```
SELETC l1.Start_Date, l1.Monthly_Fee, SUM(l2.Fee) as CumulativeSum
FROM Lease as l1
INNER JOIN Lease as l2 ON l1.Start_Date >= l2.Start_Date
GROUP BY l1.Start_Date, l1.Monthly_Fee
ORDER BY l1.Start_Date
```

Comment: Well done, but it's worth pointing out that the brackets will only work with MSSQL. If Madhura is using anything else they'll need to remove those.

Comment: Unfortunately your result is giving a cumulative sum. By coincidence that "works" for the first three months/leases but it isn't really what the questionn is about :( Basically it's only looking at the first month of the lease.